# how I can split a function which writes color code of an element to txt file, into 2 different functions in cypress

Tags: cypress

I have this function in cypress which determine the color code of an element and write that color code in txt file.

````
rgbToHexConverter.js'```

```export default function writeElementColorToFile(element, color, file) {
  element.invoke('css', color).then(colorCode => {
    cy.writeFile(`${file}`, rgbToHexConverter(colorCode) + '\n', { flag: 'a+' })
  })
}```

I would like to have 2 functions like getElementColorCode(element,color)=> returns colorCode and writeElementClorCodeToFile(colorcode,file)=> writes colorCode in txt file n hex format, so in future I can use them independently.
````

Answer (score 0):

You could write them as two separate Cypress custom commands as such:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('getElementColorCode', {prevSubject: 'element'}, (subject) => {
  return subject.css('color')
})

Cypress.Commands.add('writeColorCodeToFile', {prevSubject: true}, (subject, file) => {
  cy.writeFile(file, rgbToHexConverter(subject) + '\n', { flag: 'a+' });
});

// Example usage
cy.get('foo')
  .getElementColorCode()
  .writeColorCodeToFile('foo.txt');
```

So, what's happening?
In the first command, we're chaining it off of a previous subject. In the example, that's the subject yielded from `cy.get('foo')`. We've set validation in that first command to only accept elements, but if that was too strict, we could change that to `{prevSubject: true}`. We're then using [the JQuery `.css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css/) command to get the CSS Color. Since we're returning that, it is the yielded value from `.getElementColorCode()`

In the second command, we're again using the `prevSubject` to automatically pass the value in. We then need to provide our file (in the example, `foo.txt`), which we then pass into the `cy.writeFile()` command.

The first command will work fine, so long as an element is always passed in, so I don't see any need to potentially modify it. If you were thinking of not always having the second command as a child command in a Cypress chain, we could do some slight modification to allow it to sometimes be a parent chain.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('writeColorCodeToFile', {prevSubject: 'optional'}, (subject, file, color?) => {
  cy.writeFile(file, rgbToHexConverter(subject ?? color) + '\n', { flag: 'a+' });
});

// Example usage
cy.writeColorCodeToFile('foo.txt', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
// or
cy.get('foo').then(($el) => {
  cy.writeColorCodeToFile('foo.txt', $el.css('color'));
});
```